# will active message count ever be zero, when publishing and consumption match in Azure Service Bus queues?

Tags: java, azure, azureservicebus

[image]

We have a data transfer solution with Azure Service Bus as the message broker. if you see the message publishing/ consumption pattern above, it looks like the messages are consumed as soon as they are published, i.e., the *count of outgoing messages pretty much overlaps the count of incoming messages*. however, we see that the active message count (Average) is **not zero** - it looks like there is an accumulation of messages (upto 2 or 4), and then they are consumed. we see alternating *peeks and valleys in the active messages chart*.

We have the following questions -

- **How is the active messages count calculated by Azure and reported on the Metrics chart?**
- **Is the Java `QueueClient` not consuming the messages as and when they are published? is there a delay in consumption, leading to the building up of active messages in our queues?**

**Environment details**:

- Java - openjdk-11-jre
- Azure Service Bus namespace tier: Standard
- Java SDK version - 3.4.0
- number of queues - 43 with one producer and one consumer `QueueClient` per queue

Answer (score 0):

Worked offline with Lakshmi. Active message metrics are triggered every minute for a particular point of time and get the active message of the entity/namespace. Other metrics are the like IncomingMesages, OutgoingMessages count is total no of messages that were sent to the service bus or consumed by your clients per minute aggregation.

**Observation:**
The active message call was at the same time when the client sends the message to the service bus and there was still one active message that to be consumed by the client (milliseconds).